# Recorded videos with MediaRecorder play only the first frame in Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, mediarecorder

I have reports from several users on distinct Samsung devices (J6, S6, S7, ...), where recorded videos do not play, so seem to be corrupted.
The playback seems stuck/frozen at the first frame, while the audio plays correctly.

The issue happens with videos recorded using Android's [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) API.

The information I could gather is that it happens when a device goes into deep-sleep, so turning the screen off and perform no usage of the device for several minutes. When the devices becomes active again, then for some **still unknown reasons**, a new recording produces an excessively large delta duration between the first and second frame, giving the impression on playback that is frozen or has only 1 frame.

I've found around the internet the issue reported in different sites, yet no proper solution. Has anyone found a workaround? Samsung doesn’t seem to acknowledge the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation have shown that the issue might be caused by a system bug in some Samsung models.

Inspecting the corrupted videos sent by some users I could confirm that in all the affected devices the first frame has an exaggerated large delta duration time.

So, with an incorrect delta time, it makes the impression that the video is frozen, when is actually just showing in screen the first frame as per its defined delta duration time, which for corrupted videos is tremendously long.

To fix these samples, I replaced the delta time of the first frame with the value from the second frame (only the first frame is affected). Then the video plays correctly as expected. I used [IsoParser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/releases) for this task.

But this is not a proper solution, as it means to have to check every video and repackage it if affected, as there is no way to fix it in-place. The operation requires to create a new video file, copy the contents of the original with the correct delta time, and replace the original file with the fixed one.

The proper solution would be to find out how the MediaRecorder API computes delta times, and why in some scenarios for the affected devices produces an invalid value for the first frame.

My only guess is that if by any chance the MediaRecorder implementation uses the System.nanoTime clock, then I read in some StackOverflow posts that this system clock gives sometimes a bizarre value when coming back from a device deep-sleep. If that was the real issue then the only real solution would be that Samsung fixes their implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough writeup.  I believe I'm seeing the same issue (my test device is a Samsung Galaxy S7).  Inspected the frames using ffprobe and indeed see the wrong duration on the first video frame as you said.  Just wondering if you ever found any new information since you wrote this answer 2 years ago? Thank you.